# Android - Java / c# /c++ Speed

Tags: c#, java, c++, android

I am to start writing my first Android application starting next week here at work. I am curious about the video and results of it found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=It8xPqkKxis

The submitter indicates that c++/c# runs faster than Java on the Android platform though this was on Android 1.5.

At any rate, can anyone confirm that there is indeed a increase in performance using c++ or c# on 2.2? Our application will need as much speed and batterylife it can get.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Per Woot4Moo's comment, yes, which implementation runs the best? Take all factors into account including runtimes, frameworks, compilers ... There is a obvious difference and I want to know if anyone has experience with writing c++/c# on android

Comment: People tend to think languages have speeds, they do not.  Interpreters and Compilers have speeds.

Comment: Updated question. Thanks Woot for helping me clarify

Comment: If it's your first app, I'd strongly recommend writing it entirely in Java.  If it's not fast enough, you can rewrite the slow parts in C++ later.  Your life will be much easier if you stick to a single language, and the Android development environment works best with Java.

Answer (score 1):

As for C++: It is the "native language" the Android is written in. It probably isn't interpreted like Java is. As for C# it is most likely compiled too. And, usually, when a language is interpreted it is slower than another language (or itself maybe) if it is compiled.

Comment: Not quite right, most "Android" code is written in Java. The operating system it runs on is Linux, which is C/C++/assembly/etc but all the stuff we think of as Android--Activity, Service, WindowManager--is written in Java.

Comment: @satur9nine: And how do you think the Java interpreter was made? With C/C++/Asm.